# Can these items/elements represent the mentioned fields/services to design a logo?

Tags: logo, design-principles, designers, branding

Okay, I'm designing a logo for an NGO whose tagline talks about **education**, **science** and **beginning** of all its relevant services. I'm using a few *objects* (in multiple options, different combinations, not all in one) to create the design and in some options mixing those options with the initials of the original brand name of NGO.

Here are these:

1) Search/find icon (that we see in almost all search boxes on web on right side). I'm using it manually to relate with science, because in real world it is called magnifying glass in Physics

2) Space Rocket (to represent science)

3) Pencil (to represent education)

4) 2-3 horizontal lines (to represent paragraph and education)

5) A resume icon (a triangle we see in music applications that we click to resume/start music). Using it to show that it's beginning of the services

6) A settings icon (gear icon) to represent technology

7) A bulb to represent science and technology

Now, **(1)** do these relations I'm thinking to relate with brand name, actually relate or is it just me thinking like this? In simpler words, can these objects be used to represent the mentioned functions/services/fields (I don't know what to say it exactly in English).

If yes, **(2)** can non design people also relate it this way? Or not at all?

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you're asking. Can you include a visual of what you mean? Even if it's recreating it in basic form.

Comment: Zach Saucier I wonder how it can be very hard. Hard is possible. Very hard? Would you please elaborate? Maybe I could edit then. No I can't add images. Anyone can comment then I need free design.

Comment: @curious can you please revert the edit?

Comment: @Vikas No, that was unfriendly to begin with. Do not add it back.

Comment: But those close votes are also unfriendly. What's so wrong about writing truth which is has 1000000% possibilities of happening? I quite don't understand that.

Comment: @Vikas Votes are just that: votes. You are assuming people are being unfriendly. Your question is not currently closed. Try to understand why people vote to close by asking them what you could improve before reaching 5 close votes. You can always salvage your question by editing it.

Comment: I tried but so called people don't reply.

Comment: Vikas, in all fairness, I have struggled and tried to help you improve your questions. You either don't care to listen or feel you know what's better/more suited based upon this sites guidelines. It's unfair to blame others because you *still* aren't understanding how Stack Exchange sites work. Poor, down voted, or closed, questions are no one else's fault but your own. The MOST any other user could do is cast **one** vote, which never closes a question.

Comment: @Scott I mean the other most users who don't start a topic and that don't reply.

Comment: Users *are* commenting via votes. They are saying the question is either unsuitable, unhelpful, no effort is shown, etc. And if edits are made to address such issues in the question, those votes can *just as easily be removed* by those users. Stack has automated mechanisms in place to prevent serial voting and most "vendetta" voting. **No one** is out to get you and playing the martyr will most likely result in **more** negative votes, not less.

Comment: This question has so much meaning, it becomes meaningless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your list of clichés so **overwhelmingly clichéd** that the general public will see and recognize those clichés?

Yes, in all probability the general public will draw the same lines as you are. None of the proposed imagery is so "new" or "original" as to create roadblocks in understanding. In fact, I'd wager it's possible to find all of those images, in icon form, via the NounProject or something similar.

Now.. is any of that good or desired where a **logo** design is concerned... well that may be another matter entirely.

Comment: thank you so much for telling me about https://thenounproject.com/ 1 upvote for that. Secondly, can you please elaborate this: *None of the proposed imagery is so "new" or "original" as to create roadblocks in understanding.*